# How do I install LetsEncrypt SSL onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk application running Tomcat 8 with Java 8 Platform

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, lets-encrypt

I would like this website [www.albunack.net](http://www.albunack.net) to support SSL

It is installed as a Java WAR file onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk at albunack.elasticbeanstalk.com, dns (as single instance) configuration is under Route 53 control.

I don't have much system admin knowledge, what is the easiest way to enable SSL for this

This is a very specific request, so I'm hoping for a series of specific steps to achieve this rather than general advice.

Comment: The answer is actually right. Using the AWS Beanstalk you decided to offload a lot of maintenance details to aws, e. g. the load balancer, ssl,... and  now you are trying to force something out of box(a letsencrypt certificate). The easiest way (and included in pruce of the LB) is using the SSL of the load balancer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: ok thats makes sense, but when i get to the select certifcate the ones listed do not match the domain

Comment: Then request a certificate that is matching the  domain in the Certificate Management

Comment: okay got it working, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From AWS recommendation, using **ElasticBeanstalk**, the easiest way to handle the SSL is over **AWS Load Balancer**.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

From AWS, you can easily get yourself a free SSL certificate which is issued by AWS, or import your self-signed certificate into AWS ACM.

- How to issue your own public SSL certificate?
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html
- How to import your SSL certificate?
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html

If we choose ElasticBeanstalk, AWS recommends us going with Load Balancer & Auto-Scaling to leverage all of good features that provided by ElasticBeanstalk such as Blue-Green deployment model.

> Amazon Lightsail is a choice

If you manage your application with just a single EC2 instance under ElasticBeanstalk, I recommend using **Amazon Lightsail** which cost is much more better.

Reference: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-nginx

> How to install SSL on a standalone EC2 instance

Here is a very old post but you can see the overview of steps on doing it on a single EC2 instance.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/going-https-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-14-04-with-lets-encrypt-certbot-on-nginx-696770649e76/

Comment: thanks have it basically working, dont understand the signiificance of 'I recommend launching an EC2 instance from EC2 console instead. This allows you to use that EC2's public IP (or Elastic IP if you configure) while ElasticBeanstalk requires you to use its own environment URL for DNS management.' which i didnt do.

Comment: Ah, it was my exp with Elastic Beanstalk in the old time, haven't checked if it is updated or not. Long time ago, I did setup like you and have something not going well with the public IP and Beanstalk environment URL. Then my perspective is, if I have only a standalone EC2 instance for my app, I just go to EC2 service and launch it :D

Comment: Usually, if I want an architecture with Load Balancer & Auto-Scaling, ElasticBeanstalk is a good to go, just upload my code and get free SSL from ACM. There is an option that you can try, Amazon Lightsail. It is save cost than EC2 also with predefined package.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Using Amazon Lightsail, AWS publicly shares all of setup steps for you also, from setup the instance then how to install SSL step by step: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress

Comment: Im happy to use AWS certificates I only mentioned LEtsEncrupt because I knew these were free and I didnt know AWS issued free ones. I do have a follow up issue though, I dont know if yo can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493983/configuring-https-for-s3-html-files-linked-to-elastic-beanstalk-application