# How to configure https for Amazon S3 html files linked to Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https

I have added **https** support to my elastic beanstalk Java based application (at https://www.albunack.net) by adding Amazon certificate to the load balancer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434723/how-do-i-install-letsencrypt-ssl-onto-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-running), registered for the domain names albunack.net and *.albunack.net

The part that is running on elastic beanstalk is working correctly, however if I move to some static html files that are stored on Amazon S3 bucket called **reports.albunack.net** it just hangs

e.g. https://reports.albunack.net/new_acoustid_report1_1.html

the non https url works fine

e.g. https://reports.albunack.net/new_acoustid_report1_1.html

Do I need to do something on **S3** as well ?

Comment: Can you describe more about how your application handles/uses those static files? using AWS SDK to interact with S3? and how you configure your S3 bucket?

Comment: The application would just link to them from http://www.albunack.net/reports.jsp (currently we link to the http version), the files are generated on an EC2 instance and uploaded to S3 periodically. Im sorry I cannot remember how the reports.albunack.net S3 bucket was created (it was years ago) but it is publicably accessible

Answer (score 3):

Basically, S3 does not serve HTTPS traffic. If you want to access your static contents with in-transit encryption, you need to have a **CloudFront distribution** in front of it, or we can say that we need a **CDN**.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/

For SSL certificate, you can issue a free one as you did with your Load Balancer, but you need to issue it under `North Virginia region` to make it work with your CloudFront distribution.

After that, you can update your DNS management with a CNAME to your CloudFront distribution which will be a DNS name.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

After all, you and your app should be access one of your image with HTTPS.

```
https://<your-domain>/image1.png
```

Comment: okay well i have similar problem with artist.albunack.net (which does use cloudfront, these are dynamically created pages first time requested then stored on s3 and accessed via cloudfront) so Ill see if I can get that working first.